# Is it possible to create separate bin for each cross product in a cross coverage bin

Tags: system-verilog

I have two coverpoints that I want to cross as shown in the code below. In the cross coverage, I want to organize the cross values into different bins based on the value of one of the coverpoints, cp_a in this case. For example cr.a1 is the cross products of all values of b when a is 1. The example below makes one unified bin for all of the crosses that satisfies this condition. Is it possible to make one separate bin for each cross product axb where a is 1? In this case it will be 10 different bins, one for each value of b while a is 1.

For a coverpoint bin you would use `bins b [] = {[0:10]}`, but it looks like that does not work for cross.

```
module top {
  int a;
  int b;
  covergroup CG;
    cp_a : coverpoint a {
      bins a1 = {1};
      bins a2 = {2};
      bins a3 = {3};
    }
    cp_b : coverpoint b {
      bins b [] = {[0:10]};
    }
 
    cr : cross cp_a, cp_b {
      bins a1 = binsof(cp_a.a1);
      bins a2 = binsof(cp_a.a2);
      bins a3 = binsof(cp_a.a3);
    }
  endgroup
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organizing bins of a `cross` is very different from a coverpoint. You generally want to ignore bins you don't want or change the way you collect the coverpoints. In this case I think you want to break up `cp_a` into three coverpoints and create three crosses.

```
module top {
  int a;
  int b;
  covergroup CG;
    cp_a1 : coverpoint a { bins a1 = {1}; }
    cp_a2 : coverpoint a { bins a1 = {2}; }
    cp_a3 : coverpoint a { bins a1 = {3}; }
    cp_b : coverpoint b {
      bins b [] = {[0:10]};
    }
 
    cr_a1 : cross cp_a1, cp_b;
    cr_a2 : cross cp_a2, cp_b;
    cr_a3 : cross cp_a3, cp_b;
  endgroup
endmodule
```